# Duda ordenar arrays c++

Tags: c++, array, ordenar

estoy haciendo un ejercicio que consiste en dado un array de números, ordenarlo poniendo primero los números negativos y luego los positivos (el orden de los negativos y positivos da igual), y he conseguido que me funcione, pero no entiendo una cosa del segundo bucle, por que la condición de este debe ser j<MAX-1 y no j<MAX  , ya que deberia recorrer todos los numeros del array para saber que estan ordenados no? Gracias de antemano

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>


using namespace std;

const int MAX=10;
typedef array <int,MAX> Tvector;


Tvector ordenar(Tvector v);


int main()
{

  Tvector numeros= {-1, 2, 5, -4, 7, -3, 9, 45, -2, -10};


  Tvector v=ordenar(numeros);
  for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++)
  {
      cout<<v[i]<<" ";
  }



}

Tvector ordenar(Tvector v)
{

  int aux;

  for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++)
  {
      for(int j=0; j<MAX-1; j++)              // PORQUE J<MAX-1 Y NO J>MAX
      {

          if(v[j]>0&&v[j+1]<0)
          {
              aux=v[j+1];
              v[j+1]=v[j];
              v[j]=aux;
          }
      }
  }

  return v;

}
```

Comment: Porque dentro del bucle accedes a `j+1`, es decir el elemento siguiente, por lo tanto tu último elemento a considerar tiene que ser el penúltimo. Por cierto, el comentario en el código te quedó mal: `J>MAX`. :P Igual esta lógica es muy rudimentaria y lenta, se puede mejorar. Es básicamente la versión rudimentaria del burbuja pero sólo considerando signo. Imagina un array de 1M de elementos, y los primeros 500K son negativos. Vas a recorrerlos millones y millones de veces innecesariamente.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias, si se que el método no es el mejor, es que todavía no nos han explicado ningún método en las clases , veré sobre que va el método burbuja, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fin de que la pregunta no quede sin respuesta, reitero mi comentario: es porque dentro del `for` interno accedes a `j + 1`, es decir el elemento siguiente, por lo tanto tu último elemento a considerar tiene que ser el penúltimo.

```
for (int j = 0; j < MAX - 1; j++)
{
    if (v[j] > 0 && v[j + 1] < 0) // aquí usas j + 1
    {
        aux = v[j + 1]; // aquí usas j + 1
        v[j + 1] = v[j]; // aquí usas j + 1
        v[j] = aux;
    }
}
```

Si utilizaras `j < MAX`, en el último ciclo `j + 1` intentaría acceder a un elemento por fuera del array.

Otra forma de hacerlo es que el `for` interno tenga efectivamente como condición `j < MAX`, pero debería iniciar en 1 en vez de 0, y en vez de `j + 1` usar `j`, y en vez de `j` usar `j - 1`, pero de esta forma puede que sea un poco menos claro.

```
for (int j = 1; j < MAX; j++)
{
    if (v[j - 1] > 0 && v[j] < 0)
    {
        aux = v[j];
        v[j] = v[j - 1];
        v[j - 1] = aux;
    }
}
```